# Append Data on new generated Element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some Data to a new generated Div element but it just wont work.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'code/submit/submitGetChat.php',
    data: "id="+chatListArray[i],
    async: false,
    success: function(data){                    
        $('#chatItemContent_' + chatListArray[i]).empty();
        $('#chatItemContent_' + chatListArray[i]).append(data);                     
        $('#chatItemContent_' + chatListArray[i]).animate({ scrollTop: $(document).innerHeight() }, 1);
    }
});
```

This is the current code. The result of an Ajax call should be appended on a Parent Element.

Comment: What is in the data?  What is returned from your AJAX call to code/submit/submitGetChat.php?

Comment: You know you're not creating the `#chatItem... ` element, you're trying to access an element that should already exist ?

Comment: This is just a snipped, all the elements exist. The request returnes some html code. (div, img.. elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here (an educated one though ;).

It looks like you're looping through a bunch of ajax calls and expecting the pass the resulting data to the relevant elements, but what you've got won't do that.  The index value is not local so it is different by the time the ajax call is completed.  Try wrapping the ajax call in an enclosure like this...

```
(function(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'code/submit/submitGetChat.php',
        data: "id=" + id,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){                    
            $('#chatItemContent_' + id).empty();
            $('#chatItemContent_' + id).append(data);
            $('#chatItemContent_' + id).animate({ scrollTop: $(document).innerHeight() }, 1);
        }
    });
})(chatListArray[i]);
```

Also, just as a side note, you can chain the functions you're using in the success callback, like this...

```
$('#chatItemContent_' + id)
    .empty()
    .append(data)
    .animate({ scrollTop: $(document).innerHeight() }, 1);
```

It's not gonna break the sound barrier or anything like that, but it's quicker to do the select once, rather than 3 times :)

Comment: Lol.  Picking Doge as my avatar has given me many lulz in comments.  So happy.  Gladly help :)